# preselected values in DateControl yii 2

Tags: php, datetime, widget, yii2

**I have the following code :**

```
$form->field($model, 'start_time')->widget(DateControl::classname(), [
                    'type'=>DateControl::FORMAT_DATETIME,
                    'displayFormat' => 'php:d-M-Y H:i:s',
                    'ajaxConversion'=>true,
                    'options' => [
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'autoclose' => true
                        ]
                    ]
                ]);
```

that works perfectly. we can select the date and time and send the data to controller to save it.

**The Problem**

When I write this same code in update form, the values that are comming from the database does not show up in the datecontrol field. Its empty.. I have tried to provide a unix type datetime and a normal string(24-jul-2015) as well but it doesn't show any thing. Does any one know how to do that ?

other fields like following seems to be working perfectly and are being populated with the values from the database

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'price')->textInput() ?>
```

Comment: I found the answer by kartik ... just add saveFormat=>'d-M-y' under displayFormat or any other formate of your choice and it will display the saved value.. simple :)

Comment: You can answer your own question since it already has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by kartik.

just add

```
saveFormat=>'d-M-y'
```

under `displayFormat` or any other formate of your choice and it will display the saved value.. simple :)